# Adding a property that sums the results of a query in Lightswitch 2012

Tags: c#, calculated-field, lightswitch-2012

I have a project using C# in Lightswitch 2012 that has the following tables:

### Clients

- Id - Integer
- CaseID - Long Integer
- FullName - String
- Address - String
- Tracking - TrackingItem Collection

### Staff

- Id - Integer
- PIN - Integer
- FullName - String
- Tracking - TrackingItem Collection

### Tracking

- Id - Integer
- Client - Client
- Staff - StaffItem
- StartDate - Date
- StartTime - DateTime
- EndTime - DateTime
- Units - Double (calculated field)
- TogetherTime - Boolean

Relationships are as follows: Each tracking object must have at least one Client and at least one Staff, and each Client and Staff can have many Tracking objects.  I currently have a query called TrackingFilter that lets users filter the Tracking table on a search screen called SearchTrackingFilter by client name, staff name, a date range, and whether or not the item is marked as together time.  This also displays the calculated field "Units" in the results table.  What I am trying to do is add a text field to the screen above the results table that shows the total number of units that the query returned with whatever criteria the user selected.  I'm a bit stuck at this point and don't know what to do.  I can add labels and such to the screen just fine, but I can't seem to edit any sort of code or anything that would let me add up the total number of units returned by the query.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same requirement.
You can access the DataWorkspace with `this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData` and add your filter parameters to it.

For example:

```
IDataServiceQueryable<Invoice> queryInvoiceTotal = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Invoices;
if (drdCustomer != null)
    queryInvoiceTotal = queryInvoiceTotal.Where(q => q.Customer.Id == this.drdCustomer.Id);
if (InvoiceState != null)
    queryInvoiceTotal = queryInvoiceTotal.Where(q => q.InvoiceState == InvoiceState);
if (InvoiceDateStart != null)
    queryInvoiceTotal = queryInvoiceTotal.Where(q => q.Date >= InvoiceDateStart);
if (InvoiceDateEnd != null)
    queryInvoiceTotal = queryInvoiceTotal.Where(q => q.Date <= InvoiceDateEnd);
var data = queryInvoiceTotal.Execute();
decimal? totalNetto = data.Sum(q => q.SumNetto);
```

You could also access the so called VisualCollection query in the screen, but pls note that this would only summarize the data which is currently visible in the screen/grid. So e.g. if you are only showing 45 items per page it would only summarize those 45 items up.